# Eclipse - how to organize or link common code?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have several Eclipse Projects:

CommonCodeProject

- com.mycommonpackage1
- com.mycommonpackage2

MyProject1

MyProject2

Currently I link the common code project with MyProject1 and MyProject2, which works.

However, what I notice is that the entire CommonCodeProject will be included in each project's build.  Both MyProject1 and MyProject2 will include all the packages & java classes in CommonCodePackage.

So if I were to add package com.mycommonpackage3 to the CommonCodeProject, it'll also be included in MyProject1 and MyProject2.

I'm wondering what other options Eclipse might have to better organize and use common code -- common packages and/or java classes?
Is it possible to link / include only certain packages that a project needs?
Should I put each common package into its own Library, and include the library in the projects that need it?

So for instance, if MyProject1 needs all the common code (all packages & java classes), then linking the source works fine.

But what if MyProject2 really only needs to use certain common packages/classes, say it needs only com.mycommonpackage2.  How can I include / link only that package?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

If your CommonCodeProject hosts features that are so fundamental different that you use them separately quite often, they should not be in the same project from the start.

Neglecting proper modularity/dependency in the beginning is the foundation for failure if your project is some 100.000 lines of code.

The principal of modularity is nearly always the same on each level (method/class/package/jar) -> put together what belongs together according to some consistent ruleset. For me the most important being: There are very few external relationships and many internal. Putting together two unrelated features in a project violates the second.

Comment: Most of the common code I have is database Entity classes, but my main modules may not need all the Entity classes but only some of them, based on the database schema.  Perhaps each database schema Entity classes should be in their own Eclipse Project?  I started down this road at least for one schema.